# Can I make "git status" show the file size of untracked files?

Tags: git

It would be very handy for me to see the file size of untracked files. And maybe the old/new size of changed files.

Is it possible to configure git in a way to show it?

Answer (score 11):

```
git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -hs | sort -h
```

1. `The git status --porcelain` will show the file changed.

```
$ git status
?? IMG_20160813_205506_AO_HDR.jpg
?? IMG_20160813_205539_AO_HDR.jpg
?? IMG_20160813_211139_HDR.jpg
?? IMG_20160814_143649_HDR.jpg
```

2. `awk '{print $2}'` will extract the content after `??`
3. Finally, the `ls -hs` will show the size of each file in a human readable format. and the `sort -h` will sort them by size.

**Sample Output:**

```
$ git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -hs | sort -h
136 IMG_20160813_205506_AO_HDR.jpg
384 IMG_20160813_205539_AO_HDR.jpg
784 IMG_20160813_211139_HDR.jpg
5667898 IMG_20160814_143649_HDR.jpg
```

Comment: I got this error "xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option". The output after command "awk '{print $2}' gave me text that include: "Assets/Editor (line break) "Assets/Editor

Comment: @TrongNguyen Maybe that occurs because there is space or double quote in your file name. You need to modify the command to adjustify it. Here the command meets the majority requirements.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot make `git status` do that.

You may not *need* to make `git status` do that, because you can write your *own* command that does that instead.  Use:

```
git -C "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)" ls-files --other --exclude-standard
```

to obtain the file list.  You can then use whatever command you like to view statistics about those files.  You may want to run this command immediately after `git status` and have `git status` suppress its own listing with `--untracked-files=no`.  For instance:

```
alias st='git status -uno;
  git -C "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)" ls-files --others --exclude-standard -z | 
  xargs -0 ls -lR'
```

Here I've used `-z` as well since the command I am using, `xargs -0 ls -l`, can handle that, and expressed this as a *shell* alias rather than a *Git* alias.

There is a flaw here.  While `git status` with `-uall` will enumerate all the untracked files within a directory, `git ls-files --others` won't: it behaves like a default `git status`, summarizing such files by printing only the containing directory name.  The `ls -l` here will show the files within the directory; to stop that, use `ls -ld` instead, but of course you won't see any file sizes.

(To get modified files, use `git ls-files -m` rather than `--others`.)

Answer (score 6):

Try to add the following codes into your .bashrc or .zshrc. And then use `gst` to get a pretty format output with file size information

```
alias gst="git_status_size"
git_status_size(){
    git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -hl | sort -r -h | awk '{print $5 "\t" $9}'
}
```

Output:

```
$ gst
287MB   video.mp4
53B     README.md
33B     222.txt
18B     333.txt
6B      111.txt
```

Comment: This script is not optimized if you have deleted files or if you are not running the command form the root of your repository. I have edited this to solve both the problems : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792144/6224662

Answer (score 1):

This command will work with filenames that contain whitespace.

```
git status --porcelain | awk '{print substr($0,4)}' | xargs ls -hs | sort -h
```

Based on @ramwin's answer.

If your files have whitespace in them, running ramwin's command will give you error "xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option"

I modified the awk part to `awk '{print substr($0,4)}'`, substr($0,4) takes the output from git status and get the texts from the 4th character to the end of each line. Example:

If git status --porcelain give you: `?? "folder/Folder with whitespace/fileA.ext"`

awk '{print substr($0,4)} will output `"folder/Folder with whitespace/fileA.ext"`

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers use `git status --porcelain`, which returns file paths from the root of the repository.

Using `git status -s` would be preferred if we want relative file paths. I have written the below command to show only files that exist (deleted file can't exist) and can be used anywhere.

```sh
git status -s | grep -v D.* | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -hl | sort -r -h | awk '{print $5 "\t" $9}'
```

You can also add the following to your `.bashrc` file to use as an alias.

```sh
alias gst="git_status_size"
git_status_size(){
        git status -s | grep -v D.* | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -hl | sort -r -h | awk '{print $5 "\t" $9}'
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
7.8K    nnp_replication_attempt_1/scaling.data
7.8K    enhanced_sampling_1/scaling.data
5.3K    nvt_transfer_H_template.lmp
5.3K    ../replication_attempt_1/nvt_stretch_bond.lmp
719     enhanced_sampling_1/z1-ada.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me: `git status -s . | awk '{print $2}' | xargs ls -s M -S`

Explanation

### git

- `-s: list size using current directory as reference rather than repo root (which is what` --porcelain` asks for).
- `.` restricts output to only files in current directory or below.

### ls

- `-s M`: print sizes in MB.
- `-S` argument for `ls` sorts the output by size and avoids the need for `sort`.