# "git add ." returns a blank line in terminal

Tags: git, command-line, terminal

I am trying to push updates to my git repo from my CLI, but "git add ." is not doing anything. When I run that command, I get a blank line in my terminal that does nothing, and I eventually kill the process. I would share code, but I have no idea where the source of the problem could even be. I did recently add a collaborator to my git repo, so maybe that has something to do with it? I've never had this problem before. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

EDIT: this is the output of git status:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   client/src/components/ExploreDirectory/ExploreDirectory.js
    modified:   client/src/components/ExploreDirectory/exploredirectory.css
    modified:   client/src/components/ProposalBox/ProposalBox.js
    modified:   client/src/components/ProposalBox/proposalbox.css
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/all/All.js
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/all/all.css
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/arts/Arts.js
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/arts/arts.css
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/directAction/DirectAction.js
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/directAction/directaction.css
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/explore.css
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/sciences/Sciences.js
    modified:   client/src/pages/explore/sciences/sciences.css

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .DS_Store
    models/
    node_modules/
    src/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: what is the output of `git status` ?

Comment: always check what files are about to be added using `git status` to make sure `git add .` has something to work with.

Comment: added "git status" output to the question above!

Answer (score 2):

That happens when git add is in the process of adding;

- too many files
- and/or files which too big

That is why `git status` can help pinpoint what you are about to add.
See "[Can I make “git status” show the file size of untracked files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54695478/6309)"

Comment: added "git status" output to my question. do i have to add each of these files individually to stage them for commit?

Comment: @user72503948573038 You need first to add a .gitingore tailored for node/npm projects: https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/node. Then you can add everything in one go: `git add .`: it will not include files which are not needed and/or potentially too big. Because they will be ignored by the `.gitignore` file.