# What is the best way to shrink the size of a .git directory?

Tags: git

The total size of my local directory `exospace` is 5.04 GB. The `.git` directory within is 4.9 GB. What is the best way to shrink the size of this directory given that only 0.14 GB / 5.04 GB is being used for files/directories relevant to my actual project?

[image]

Comment: `git prune` followed by `git gc` for a start

Comment: Stop tracking the files that aren't relevant to your project!

Comment: `git gc --aggressive` is nice to perform thorough cleaning too, but can be very long and resource-consuming. Start it when you have nothing better to do at a time.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned the [reflog --expire/gc combination before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116892/6309).

But first, for testing, clone your local repository in another folder, just to check that indeed your checked out folder would be much smaller.

In your original local folder (the one with 5GB of data), list [your untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801554/6309), and [check their size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54695478/6309): that will give you an idea of the issue.